# Webview in android suddenly stops when button is pressed

Tags: android, webview

```
    package com.example.karla;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient()); 
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");


}
```

}
`class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {
         @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }`

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
```

}

```
package com.example.karla;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;   
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button button;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = this;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }

    });

}
```

}

My android application suddenly stops when I press the button. I also want the website to load in the webview not in the browser so i override the urlloading. I dont know what to do?  What should i do?

Comment: You are accessing your webView before it is initialized. Move webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());  under your findViewById call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
```

If you want to let the webview load this page, don't do `view.loadUrl()`: just return `false`.

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;

    }
```

Returning `true` will prevent webview from loading the url which means you should do something with it instead. For example, instead of navigating to a "help" page, you could show a screen inside the app with help.